# What type of typedef is this?

Tags: c, typedef

Here is the sample code

```
typedef int INT, *INTPTR, ONEDARR[10], TWODARR[10][10];
```

What does the above code means?
`INT` is the alias for `int`. Rest of the code what is happening?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/typedef has a similar example with explanation.

Answer (score 8):

The one-line `typedef` in the question is a shortcut for

```
typedef int INT;
typedef int *INTPTR;
typedef int ONEDARR[10];
typedef int TWODARR[10][10];
```

Then `INT` is an alias for type `int`.
`INTPTR` is an alias for type `int *`.
`ONEDARR` is an alias for type `int [10]`.
`TWODARR` is an alias for type `int [10][10]`.

(https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/typedef)

Comment: How is ONEDARR is an alias for type int [10]

Comment: @wupiku If you declare `ONEDARR my_var;`, it's the same as `int my_var[10];`

Comment: ONEDARR my_var; should be int my_var how is it int my_var[10];

Comment: @wupiku Why should it be `int my_var`? The typedef declares the name `ONEADDR` to apply to all the declarators in the declaration, which are `int` and `[10]`. Therefore, `ONEADDR` is an alias for `int[10]`.

Comment: Can anybody make it simple I do not understand.

Comment: @wupiku may be should you have a look at the documentation. I'm afraid we are all going to copy its explanations little by little here.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following declaration

```
int INT, *INTPTR, ONEDARR[10], TWODARR[10][10];
```

It declares four variables with type specifier `int`:

```
scalar variable INT
pointer *INTPTR
one-dimensional array ONEDARR[10]
and two-dimensional array TWODARR[10][10]
```

Then using the typedef

```
typedef int INT, *INTPTR, ONEDARR[10], TWODARR[10][10];
```

then the names of variables mean not objects but aliases for types that had the variables if they were declared without the typedef.

So `INT` means the type `int`, `INTPTR` means the type `int *`, `ONEDARR` means the type `int[10]`, and `TWODARR` means the type `int[10][10]`.

So now you have a choice whether to declare an array the following way

```
int a'10][10];
```

or to specify its type using an alias for the type of the array

```
TWODARR a;
```

Consider one more example.

Let's assume you have a function declaration

```
int f( int x, int y );
```

It has the type `int( int, int )`. Now you want to name this type that instead of this long record `int( int, int )` to use a shorter record. Then you can use a typedef like

```
typedef int FUNC( int x, int y );
```

and as result the name `FUNC` now denotes the type `int( int, int )`.